# Is it possible to read a csv file in Vega with a custom delimiter, such as ;?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have a csv file that has a custom delimiter, such as `;`.  I would like to load it into Vega a la:

```
"data": { "url": "https://url.csv",
          "format":{"type":"csv", 
          "sep":";"
        }
```

Here of course the last line does not exist in the current Vega schema.

This is akin to pandas `pd.read_csv(sep=';')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```json
"data": { "url": "https://url.csv",
          "format":{"type":"dsv", "delimiter":";"}
        }
```

See https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/data.html#dsv for more information.

Comment: Thanks jake, this is exactly what I wanted - my bad I saw the standard `csv` and `tsv` options, but totally slid over the `dsv`.